# Labelling and current arrow in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

Ok so currently I have managed to output the following circuit (and following code) :

[image: circuit]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
       (0,0) to [R, l_=$R_1$] (2,0)
       to [short] (6,0)
       to [R, l_=$R_3$] (6,4)
       to [short] (6,5)
       to [short] (0,5)
       to [V, l_=$E_1$] (0,2.5)
       to [V, l_=$E_2$] (0,0.5)
       to [short] (0,0)
       (4,0) to [V, l_=$E_3$] (4,2.5)
       to [R, l_=$R_2$] (4,4.5)
       to [short] (4,5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

And I'm trying to add currents and voltage arrows, but the documentation for circuitikz didn't help. 
So the goal would be to add arrows for example an upward one near E_1, downward one near E_2 or one going right below R_1. Also I'd like to add current arrow for example, an arrow going up on the wire above E_1 labelled i_1. I'd appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ike this?

[image]

Probably are missed some arrows or some are on wrong positions. This can be easilly to correct.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
       (0,0) to [R, l_=$R_1$] (2,0)
       to [short] (6,0)
       to [R, l_=$R_3$] (6,4)
       to [short] (6,5)
       to [short] (0,5)
       to [V=$E_1$, i=$i_1$] (0,2.5)  % <---
       to [V<=$E_2$] (0,0.5)          % <---
       to [short] (0,0)
       (4,0) to [V, l_=$E_3$] (4,2.5)
       to [R, l_=$R_2$] (4,4.5)
       to [short] (4,5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes like that thanks !